# How to automatically show menu button when adding a drawer in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigation-drawer

I've added `Drawer` to my `flutter` application, but there is no menu button showing in the app bar to be responsible for opening it. I know I can do it programmatically  but in the official documentation, it says it should be added automatically, but it is not showing for me

here is my code :

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment following line will solve your issue.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
     //   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
```